# How to pass when variable = null in python 3

Tags: python, null, python-3.4

so far I have this:

```
import datetime
f = open("log.txt", "a", encoding='UTF-8')
print ("Log file created")
print ("Enter /close to leave.")
spc = " "
while 1:
    msg = input(">>:")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now1 = str(now)
    if msg == None:
        pass
    if msg == " ":
        pass
    else:
        msg2 = now1+spc+msg+"\n"
        if msg == "/close":
            exit()
        f.write(msg2)
        f.flush()
```

However, this line is not functioning as I want it, it still returns a blank line on the log file:

```
if msg == None:
    pass
```

I want it to not return anything and simply continue the while loop, How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using

```
if msg is None:
    pass
```

**Edit**

You're missing what the pass function is all about. I would re-write your look like so. This way we're only processing this if the msg is not one of the bad input. Once we're done we break out of the loop.

```
...
while 1:
    msg = input(">>:")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now1 = str(now)
    if not msg in [None, " "]
        msg2 = now1+spc+msg+"\n"
        if msg == "/close":
            exit()
            f.write(msg2)
            f.flush()
            break
```

Comment: `None == None`, so this won't make a difference.

Comment: perfect, thanks. I guess it was just a mistake on my part (its my 3rd day with python)

Comment: @ChrisM. You'll find more flow control example at this link. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: @jwodder - My thinking, as well. In fact, using 'is' instead of '==' could have unintended consequences : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: I believe you mean "`not in`", not "`is in`" (which isn't even valid Python).

Comment: @shadow the "is None" comparison is called out in PEP8 "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators."

Comment: @Slick - I'd forgotten that, thanks! Regardless, looking at the source code, how exactly would msg be None, anyway? raw_input() will return a string, no matter what, right? Seems like checking for None is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of the rest of the loop will still continue after `pass`, and as `None` does not equal `" "`, this means the block beginning with `msg2 = now1+spc+msg+"\n"` will be executed.  You need to either unite the `if ... if ... else` into a single `if` block by changing `if msg == " ":` to `elif msg == " ":` or else change `if msg == None: pass` to `if msg == None: continue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    msg2 = now1+spc+msg+"\n"
    if msg == "/close":
        exit()
    f.write(msg2)
    f.flush()

except:
    pass #example for a function: return None or raise
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code works, and maybe tailor it to the example given?

Comment: adjusted to the question

Answer (score -1):

Your condition doesn't make any sense. The `input` function will never return `None`, only strings.

If you want to skip empty strings, a better test would be `if not msg` (empty strings are "falsy"). Or, if you want to reject any all-whitespace strings, try `if not msg.strip()` (which removes leading and trailing whitespace before checking if the rest of the string is empty or not).

Further, it's rarely a good idea to write an `if` statement that just contains `pass`. Instead, invert the test so that the condition is true for cases where you want to run some code (in this case, when `msg` is not empty or all whitespace) and simply omit the cases where you'd do nothing:

```
while 1:
    msg = input(">>:")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now1 = str(now)
    if msg.strip():               # msg is not empty or all whitespace
        msg2 = now1+spc+msg+"\n"
        if msg == "/close":
            exit()
        f.write(msg2)
        f.flush()
```

One final issue (unrelated to the main question). Python's `exit` function is primarily intended for use in the interactive interpreter. It is added to the builtins by the `site` module, and so it won't exist if Python was run with the `-S` flag. If you want to close the interpreter, you should instead call `sys.exit`, raise a `SystemExit` exception, or just run off the end of the main module (a `break` statement would probably do that for the loop you've shown here, or perhaps a `return` if you're in a function somewhere).